# Add a newline every set amount of letters in std::string

Tags: c++

I'm working with a few long strings inside a C++ program (up to 65535 letters).
What am looking for is a way to add a new line every set amount of letters with an function like this:

```
addNewLinesToString(std::string* string, u8 lettersBetween newline);
```

Which would work like this:

```
string test = "Testing1234567";
addNewLinesToString(&test, 7); //test == "Testing\n1234567\n"
```

I have yet to find such a function that only used the standard class library (C and/or C++)

If somebody has a simple solution for this would be great :)
Thanks.

Comment: One option would be to split the string into `length/newline` substrings and rebuild your string. Not sure about performance though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string insert_newlines(const std::string &in, const size_t every_n)
{
    std::string out;
    out.reserve(in.size() + in.size() / every_n);
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < in.size(); i++) {
        if (!(i % every_n) && i) {
            out.push_back('\n');
        }
        out.push_back(in[i]);
    }
    return out;
}
```

This:

- allocates memory exactly once.
- doesn't make the mistake of using `int` where `size_t` or `std::string::size_type` is required, so you don't run into strange problems for large strings or embedded platforms.
- runs in linear `O(n)` time.
- has an functional interface (rather than modifying the string in-place), an algorithm that modifies the input string and runs in `O(n)` time would be much more complex.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `string::insert` for this purpose.

```
addNewLinesToString(std::string& str, int sep)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i += sep)
        str.insert(i, "\n");
}
```

But this will be O(n^2) (as pointed by @stefan) , you can also

```
addNewLinesToString(std::string& str, int sep)
{
    string ans;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < str.size())
    {
        if (i % sep == 0 && i)
            ans.push_back('\n');
        ans.push_back(str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Which uses more memory but is O(n).

Take a look at examples: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/

Comment: This algorithm is `O(n^2)`. We can easily create an algorithm that runs on `O(n)` time.

Comment: @BillLynch oops, fixed. Thanks

Comment: Your so-called `O(n)` algorithm is actually `O(log(n))` because you're doing `log(n)` memory allocations. It will also insert an newline at the very first position in the string, which is incorrect according to the example in the question. Additional, one should not use `int` to count indices, use `size_t` or `std::string::size_type` instead.

Comment: @Stefan I am unable to get how the complexity of this O(log n), the `push_back` is used `n` times.

Comment: you're right. I made a typo but the editing window was over when i realized by mistake.. I meant to type `O(n log(n))`. You're required to allocate the memory beforehand to get it to `O(n)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this function:

```
void addNewLinesToString(std::string* s, int change){
   if(change <= 0)
      return;
   for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i += change){
      s.insert(i, "\n");
      i++;
   }
}
```

Edit: I don't know why your post got voted down, I up voted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not fastest, but working:

```
void addNewLinesToString (std::string* txt, int limit)
{
    if(limit <= 0)
        return;
    limit++;
    for (int i=1; i<=txt->size()/limit; i++)
            txt->insert((i*limit)-1, "\n");
}
```